# Word VBA: Find, copy and paste key phrases within document body to a bookmarked location at the top of page

Tags: vba, ms-word

**I need to find a solution to create a "Report Summary" sub that finds the top line of various result data within the word document and inserts them at the top of the page under a bookmarked location.**

Each result as a common value to be able find, extend to select the entire line and then copy. The bit i'm struggling with is getting sub to find all phrases that match the criteria and paste them at a bookmarked location at the top of the page. I can get the sub to copy the first instance of the phrase but not all instances. For context, the key phrase i'm using is " : " as all of the results contain this value. Another method i tried resulted in the sub creating an endless loop of pasting the first instance of the phrase until Word crashed. I presume i need to write a script that finds the phrase and then, once copied and pasted, moves on to the next instance and finally ends the sub when it reaches the end of the document. The following is where i currently stand:

```
Sub Report_SummaryTest()
If Selection.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
    With ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View
        .Type = wdPrintView
        .SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    End With
End If

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
With Selection.Find
    .Text = " : "
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    While .Execute
        Selection.Expand Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.Copy ' Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="RepSummary"
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.Paste
    Wend
End With
End Sub
```

The result data (upwards of 7 or 8 per report) looks like this:

**TEST RESULT ONE : POSITIVE**

**GUIDELINES:**

**Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one. Guidelines for result one.**

Ideally, i'd like the "Report Summary" to look like this:

**SUMMARY**

**TEST RESULT ONE : POSITIVE**

**TEST RESULT TWO : POSITIVE**

**TEST RESULT THREE : NEGATIVE**

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could simply use a Word Table of Contents

I do not know why you would reinvent the wheel. You can have what you want in it in particular styles or use TC fields. A Table of Contents in Word is a TOC field. You need not have page numbers and can really customize it. Here is the [Microsoft page on this field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c).

> **Syntax**
>
> When you view the TOC field in your document, the syntax looks like
> this:
>
> { TOC [Switches ] }
>
> **Switches that determine what's included in the table of contents**
>
> **\o "Levels"**
>
> Builds a table of contents from paragraphs formatted with styles that
> include outline levels (most commonly, heading styles). For example, {
> TOC \o "1-3" } lists only paragraphs formatted with styles that
> include outline levels 1 through 3. If no range of outline levels is
> specified, all outline levels used in the document are listed. Enclose
> the range numbers in quotation marks.
>
> **\t "Style,Level,Style,Level,..."**
>
> Builds a table of contents from paragraphs formatted with styles other
> than the built-in styles. For example, { TOC \t "chaptertitle,1,
> chapterhead,2" } builds a table of contents from paragraphs formatted
> with the styles "chaptertitle" and "chapterhead." The number after
> each style name indicates the table of contents entry level that
> corresponds to that style.
>
> You can use both the \o switch and the \t switch to build a table of
> contents from built-in styles and custom styles.
>
> **\u**
>
> Builds a table of contents from paragraphs whose formatting includes
> outline levels applied directly, in paragraph settings.
>
> **\c "SEQIdentifier"**
>
> Lists figures, tables, charts, or other items that are numbered by a
> SEQ (Sequence) field. Word uses SEQ fields to number items captioned
> with the Caption command (References > Insert Caption). SEQIdentifier,
> which corresponds to the caption label, must match the identifier in
> the SEQ field. For example, { TOC \c "tables" } lists all numbered
> tables.
>
> **\a Identifier**
>
> Lists items captioned with the Caption command (References > Insert
> Caption) but omits caption labels and numbers. The identifier
> corresponds to the caption label. For example, although a caption on
> page 12 is "Figure 8: Mercury", the field { TOC \a figures } displays
> entries as "Mercury............12".
>
> **Use the \c switch** to build a table of captions with labels and
> numbers.
>
> **\f EntryIdentifier**
>
> Builds a table from TC fields. If EntryIdentifier is specified, the
> table is built only from TC fields with the same identifier (typically
> a letter). For example, { TOC \f t } builds a table of contents from
> TC fields such as { TC "Entry Text" \f t }.
>
> **\l Levels**
>
> Builds a table of contents from TC fields that assign entries to one
> of the specified levels. For example, { TOC \l 1-4 } builds a table of
> contents from TC fields that assign entries to levels 1-4. TC fields
> that assign entries to lower levels are skipped.
>
> **\b BookmarkName**
>
> Collects entries only from the portion of the document marked by the
> specified bookmark.
>
> **Switches that format the page number**
>
> **\s Identifier**
>
> Includes a number such as a chapter number before the page number. The
> chapter or other item must be numbered with a SEQ field. Identifier
> must match the identifier in the SEQ field. For example, if you insert
> { SEQ chapter } before each chapter heading, { TOC \o "1-3" \s chapter
> } displays page numbers as 2-14, where "2" is the chapter number.
>
> **\d** "Separator"
>
> When used with the \s switch, specifies the character that separates
> the sequence numbers and page numbers. Enclose the character in
> quotation marks. Word uses a hyphen (-) if no \d switch is specified.
> In the table of contents generated by { TOC \o "1-3" \s chapter \d ":"
> }, a colon (:) separates chapter numbers and page numbers — for
> example, "2:14."
>
> **\p "Separator"**
>
> Specifies the character that separates an entry and its page number.
> For example, the field { TOC \p "—" }, with an em dash, displays a
> result such as "Selecting Text—53." The default is a tab with leader
> dots. Just one character is allowed; it must be enclosed in quotation
> marks.
>
> **\n Levels**
>
> Omits page numbers from the table of contents. Page numbers are
> omitted from all levels unless a range of entry levels is specified.
> For example, { TOC \n 3-4 } omits page numbers from levels 3 and 4.
> Delete this switch to include page numbers.

There is more that is not quoted here.

For more on this, see Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's [TOC Tricks and Tips](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm).